# questiong regarding memory optimzation C++

Tags: c++

I have header file as something like following.

```
class A;
class B;
class C;

Class a {
  A *a;
  B *b;
  C *c;
};
```

Now, `Class a` does not using all `A`, `B`, `C` and around 40 others. I have around 40 forward declarations... Is possible to optimize it someone.. So, I can declared pointer to class on need bases instead of wasting memory for all pointer to all 40 odd class?

Comment: You  might want to look over your design, maybe having a class-tree with a basic or abstract `a` class and inherited children that contains just the data needed? Or if the behavior of the depends more on the contained data, with not so much (or nothing) in common then just a set of separate classes.

Answer (score 2):

You can use union with type code or boost::variant

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend for now that you should make a parent class and put as children all of the A,B,C,etc... Then in class use a list of the parent class, and put whatever subclass you need on it. But having this problem is actually due to wrong object oriented design. Learn the principles of OO design of a system in Java for example and then put them in use in C++.

Answer (score 0):

Admitting you cannot rework your classes, and admitting you are using only one at time, you can use a union plus an ID or a "dynamically typed void*":

```
unsigned gen_id()
{ static unsigned id=0; ++id; return id; }

template<class T>
unsigned id_of()
{ static id = gen_id(); return id; } 

class a
{
   void* m;
   unsigned type;

public:
   template<class T>
   a(T* p) :m(p), type(id_of<T>()) 
   {}

   template<class T>
   T* get() const
   { return (id_of<T>()==type)? static_cast<T*>(m): nullptr; }
};
```

You can access a data as

```
A* pa = my_a.get();
if(pa) { /* what has to be done with A */ }
```

If you need more than one, consider a class b holding a vector of a.

For a more "standardized" implementation you can look at [boost::any](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/any.html)

Comment: Or indeed, Boost Variant